# How to retrieve Page slug in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

```
function get_template_url($template_name){
    global $wpdb;
    $ContactPage = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$template_name'" );
    foreach ($ContactPage as $slug) {
        if(get_page($slug->post_id))echo get_option('home').'/?p='.$slug->post_id;
    }
}
```

Function above working fine to get the id of pages

Im using the code below to get the page link

```
<a href="<?php get_template_url('template-contact.php') ?>" class="widget" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="CONTATTO"><span class="ico ico-phone-btn"></span></a>
```

but link returns to localhost/?p=485 how can I get url as /localhost/contact-us by slug instead of the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing an ID in your function...not a permalink. You should use [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) instead:

```
function get_template_url($template_name){
    global $wpdb;
    $permalink = '#';  // provide a default

    $ContactPage = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$template_name'" );
    foreach ($ContactPage as $slug) {
        if (get_page($slug->post_id)) {
            $permalink = get_permalink($slug->post_id);
        }
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```

And then:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_url('template-contact.php'); ?>" class="widget" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="CONTATTO">
    <span class="ico ico-phone-btn"></span>
</a>
```

However, there are additional issues with your code. For example, what happens if `$ContactPage` isn't an array? What happens if multiple pages are using that template (and, thus, there are multiple URIs returned)? Why are you using `get_page()`?

Comment: Hi rnevius your code is working fine in my wordpres sites but in some other servers its not working do you know what can be the reason? It can be a mysql version problem? Sorry for coming back into this topic but I realy dont understand why this happens that works on some wordpress sites and doesnt work on some other sites-. :(